# Web-based code review app that works with Subversion

Tags: version-control, code-review, continuous-integration

I am looking for a web-based code review app/framework that works with Subversion.

Currently, we don't do reviews (sigh). Developers check whatever they want in and it is really difficult to weed out incompetently written code after the fact. I would like unreviewed changes to be checked into branch A, then the developer submits a request for a code review, once it passes the review, it gets merged into branch B, which is where our `continuous integration` process picks it up for builds and deploys.

Comment: Integrated in the IDE? On the web? Command line? Local app?

Comment: So please update your question with this information

Comment: RE: `please update your question` -- done